# Parsing this file XML with touchXML

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, touchxml

I have this XML file:

```
<continents>
    <continent1 id="EUR" name="EUROPE"></continent1>
    <continent2 id="AME" name="AMERICA"></continent2>
</continents>
```

I tried make it with NSXMLParser, but I cannot show the results in the same time, I would try it with touchXML someone can help me?
thanks.

Comment: Your question is to broad; You need many more details. What data structure to you want to parse this XML into? What do you mean by "i can't show the results in the same time"? What do you need to do with the results? What have you tried so far?

Comment: i need show Europe and America in the iphone, if i parse only Europe with NSXMLParser it works but i want see Europe and America and i think that maybe is better make it with TouchXML, i don't understand much the different nodes from the XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Europe" and "America" are attributes of your tags. Attributes defined as "name" in the tag. You really should get familiar with `NSXMLParser` and the event driven method in which it parses. Basically you create an `NSObject` subclass to be the delegate of the `NSXMLParser` and as it encounters elements it calls delegate methods on your custom object. And this very simple XML is a perfect example to learn. For example.

This code uses ARC.

SimpleExampleParse.h:

```
@interface SimpleExampleParse : NSObject <NSXMLParserDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *continents;
-(id)initWithString:(NSString *)stringToParse;
@end
```

SimpleExampleParse.m:

```
#import "SimpleExampleParse.h"
@implementation SimpleExampleParse{
    NSXMLParser *myParser;
}
@synthesize continents;
-(id)initWithString:(NSString *)stringToParse{
    if ((self = [super init])){
        myParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:[stringToParse dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        myParser.delegate = self;
        self.continents = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [myParser parse];
    }
    return self;
}
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{
    // Check to see if this element has an attribute "name".
    NSString *name = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"name"];
    // If name is not nil add it to our Array
    if (name) [continents addObject:name];
}
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
    // We don't care your XML contains no content
}
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{
    // We don't care your XML contains no content
}
@end
```

This class is used like this:

```
NSString *stringToParse = @"<continents><continent1 id=\"EUR\" name=\"EUROPE\"></continent1><continent2 id=\"AME\" name=\"AMERICA\"></continent2></continents>";
SimpleExampleParse *parser = [[SimpleExampleParse alloc] initWithString:stringToParse];
NSLog(@"contenents %@",parser.continents);
```

The output from the log will be:

```
contenents (
    EUROPE,
    AMERICA
)
```

**Please** now that you have something working in front of you take the time to study it and examine how it works.